# in order of binary search tree

Tags: binary-search-trees

This is what I got for the in-order of the bst but it's wrong because I'm answering some questions about some successors of some of the letters and I got them wrong. so I'm wondering where in this in-order i've gone wrong? [image]

d, b, m, h, i, e, a, j, k, f, g, c

(Sorry if these questions aren't allowed here, please let me know where I can ask it if not!)

Answer (score 3):

Remember that an in-order traversal lists the elements from left-to-right, descending the tree: `Left`, `Root`, and `Right`. This means that starting from the root (`a`), we will traverse the whole left branch, *then* print `a`, and finally traverse the right branch.

You started off correct; however, your mistake was that you put `m` beforee `h`. It is an easy mistake to make so you have to be careful. The `m` node is the *right* node of `h` so the traversal for that subtree will be `h, m`. The same goes for `i` and `e` in your traveral---they should be flipped.

The correct answer for this in-order traversal is `d b h m e i a j f k c g`.